# Rendering an RJS of controller A in context of controller B

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013152/one-controller-rendering-using-another-controllers-views), but didn't receive a proper answer:

I have a `User` that has `Files`. When a `File` is updated (via AJAX) I want to refresh the `User` view.

I do this in RJS:

```
page['user'].replace_html :partial => 'users/user'
```

However, the `_user.erb.html` partial references other partials in the users directory, and e.g. for `_name.erb.html` Rails complains it can't find the template `Files/name`. (I want it to look for `Users/name`).

Is there a way to change the context of the view rendering to that of controller `Users`? I'd hate to fully-qualify all of the partial rendering requests.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try moving the _user.html.erb partial to a 'shared' folder? So the RJS would become:

```
page['user'].replace_html :partial => 'shared/user'
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html - a local variable may also need to be defined.

Comment: Hmmmm, I've just managed to implement something a bit similar in my app and it works fine - I'm guessing you've tried render 'user/name' in your _user partial?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid fully-qualifying my partial calls. rendering `user/name` will work, but I don't like the solution.