# Render template with partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, partial-views, render

I use this code in my app\views\pages\home.html.erb file

```
<%= render :template => 'users/new' %>
```

I use this code in my app\views\users\new.html.erb file

```
<%= render :partial => 'users/form' %>
```

Showing the "Home Page" I get this error:

NoMethodError in Pages#home

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

2:   <% if @user.errors.any? %>

...

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013152/one-controller-rendering-using-another-controllers-views), but it does not work. What can I do to render template with "sub-partial" correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PagesController#home() method, you'll need to set @user -- probably with:

```
@user = User.new
```

Comment: Thanks, it work. I founded that you can make the same thing with: <%= render :template => 'users/new', :object => @user = User.new %> in the home.html.erb file.

Comment: Yeah -- it's generally cleaner to do your object creation in your controllers than your views, though.

Comment: Partials are more reusable when you don't work with instance variables though, so even cleaner would be `<%= render "form", :user => @user %>` and in the partial do something like `<%= form_for user do |f| %>` (not using the ivar)